# Does iBATIS 2.3.x support foreach tag?

Tags: java, ibatis

I have a personal website which uses iBATIS 2.3.x. Recently I'm adding a complex searching feature to the site, need to query the data by a list of object, likes:

```
public Class PromotionAttribute {
    String attributeName;
    String attributeValue;
}
```

The query looks like:

```
select p.* from promotions p
join promotion_attributes pa on p.id=pa.id
where 
<foreach item="PromotionAttribute" index="index" collection="list" open="(" separator=" or " close=")">
pa.attribute_name=#{attributeName} and pa.attribute_value=#{attributeValue}#
</foreach>
```

For the above query, it's only a pseudocode since I didn't use the higher version of iBATIS, its meaning is I want to generate a dynamic query condition.

My question is:
I'm not sure whether iBATIS 2.3.x supports "foreach" tag, if not, how to implement this kind of query?

Thanks,
Shuiqing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use **"iterate"** in 2.3.* in place of foreach like below. Only iBATIS 3/ MyBATIS uses OGNL based expressions like choose, foreach, trim...

```
in Java,

        Map paramMap = new HashMap();
        paramMap.put("productTypes", productTypes);
        sqlMapClient.queryForList("getProducts", paramMap);
in xml,

<select id="getProducts" parameterClass="java.util.Map" 
resultClass="Product">
SELECT * FROM Products
<dynamic prepend="WHERE productType IN ">
<iterate property="productTypes"
    open="(" close=")"
    conjunction=",">
    productType=#productType#
 </iterate>
 </dynamic>
 </select>
```

You can use parameterClass as "java.util.Map" and pass list value by setting "productTypes" as key.

Comment: So I can specify a list of Product to the "parameterClass"?

Comment: Another similar question, if the parameterClass contains a list of object, likes:
public class PromotionAttributeQuery {
  Long categoryId;
  List<PromotionAttribute> promotionAttributeList;
}
how do I iterate its list in the SQL map?

Comment: edited the answer to use map as parameter. I hope this will answer your Q

Comment: this answer save my day, I edit the answer for correction to use square bracket []