# Printing arrayList of objects

Tags: java, arraylist, ibatis

i am using Ibatis 2 and i am asking how to print array of objects (as the official docs are gone). This is the example data similar to the one i have:

```
[
    {
        "firstStr": "D392",
        "secondStr": "N3895"
    },
    {
        "firstStr": "D624",
        "secondStr": "M2435"
    },
    {
        "firstStr": "T4543",
        "secondStr": "K9345"
    }
]
```

This data is defined as `ArrayList`. The objects inside array are defined as `Map`:

```
Map<String,String> data = new HashMap();
data.put("firstStr","D392");
data.put("secondStr","N3895");
...

ArrayList<Map> insert = new ArrayList<Map>();
insert.add(data);
```

I need to map this data in sql template using `<iterate>` (because in my version foreach is not available). What i currently have:

```sql
<select parameterClass="ArrayList">
    select * from something
    where str IN
    <iterate property="insert">
        #[].firstStr$, #[].secondStr#
    </iterate>
</select>
```

I am getting the following error:

```
String index out of range: -1
```

What could be the cause of this problem?

EDIT: Dont ask me to update or to use another dependency because it is not possible due to software limitations!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does iBATIS 2.3.x support foreach tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7859338/does-ibatis-2-3-x-support-foreach-tag)

Comment: Not a duplicate, please read entire question. I know that foreach is not supported. `<iterate>` is simplified (it omits open, close and conjunction)

Comment: @dbl i did it as in the question mentioned abowe and it is returning the error!

Comment: I've never used iBatis and therefore never read the docs for it... Pointed this thread out with the intention to help you... I'm sorry if it was in no use for you...

Comment: Consider switching to MyBatis instead (MyBatis is the successor to iBatis). Also, with some googling you can still find iBatis 2 documentation, eg on https://ibatis.apache.org/docs/java/

Comment: @MarkRotteveel read entire question. I specifically wrote: Dont ask me to update or to use another dependency because it is not possible due to software limitations!

Comment: That sounds like an artificial limitation to me, and if you have sufficient reasons to do so, things can change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you are right, you just got one small typo in your code. Remove `property="insert"` in your `<iterate>` statement:

```sql
<select parameterClass="ArrayList">
    select * from something
    where str IN
    <iterate>
        #[].firstStr$, #[].secondStr#
    </iterate>
</select>
```